# R: suitable plot to display data with skewed counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data like:

```
Name     Count
Object1  110
Object2  111
Object3  95
Object4  40
...
Object2000 1
```

So only the first 3 objects have high counts, the rest 1996 objects have fewer than 40, with the majority less than 10. I am plotting this data with `ggplot` bar like:

```
ggplot(data=object_count, mapping = aes(x=object, y=count)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

My plot is as below. As you can see, because there are so many objects with low counts, the width of the graph is very long, and the width of the bar is tiny, which is almost invisible for the hight-counts objects. Is there a better way to represent this data? My goal is to show a few top-count objects and to show there are many low-count ones. Is there a way to group the low count ones together?

[image]

Comment: did you consider a histogram?

Comment: You might consider sorting the objects by count, e.g. `aes(x=forcats::fct_reorder(object,count), y=count)) `

Comment: @wusel histogram obviously does not address my need. It would be the count of the number of `count`... Which means my `Object1` only counts 1, since there is only one `110` value

Comment: @JonSpring I would still get a very long graph. Should I combine all objects with count < 10 into one, and call it Others?

Comment: If instead of plotting the counts, you plot the frequencies, then you could stick to plotting only the frequencies greater than a value of your choice. This would not show all of the information of course, but it would be more informative than dropping the low values while plotting the counts. An alternative approach is to show 2 graphs: one which shows a distribution of your objects by count, then a bar plot of only your top values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your data looks something like this:

```
set.seed(1)
object_count <- tibble(
  obj_num = 1:2000,
  object = paste0("Object", obj_num),
  count = ceiling(20 * rpois(2000, 10) / obj_num)
)
head(object_count)
## A tibble: 6 x 3
#   obj_num object  count
#     <int> <chr>   <dbl>
#1        1 Object1   160
#2        2 Object2   100
#3        3 Object3    46
#4        4 Object4    55
#5        5 Object5    56
#6        6 Object6    40
```

Sure enough, when I plot that with `ggplot(object_count, aes(object, count)) + geom_col() + [theme stuff]` I get a similar figure.

[image]

---

Here are some strategies "to show a few top-count objects and to show there are many low-count ones."

#### Histogram

A vanilla histogram might not be clarifying here, since the important big values appear dramatically less often and would not be prominent enough:

```
ggplot(object_count, aes(count)) +
  geom_histogram()
```

[image]

But we could change that by transforming the y axis to bring more emphasis to small values. The `pseudo_log` transformation is nice for that since it works like a log transform for large values, but linearly near -1 to 1. In this view, we can clearly see where the outliers with just one appearance are, but also see that there are many more small values. The `binwidth = 1` here could be set to something wider if the specific values of the big values aren't as important as their general range.

```
ggplot(object_count, aes(count)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "pseudo_log",
                     breaks = c(0:3, 100, 1000), minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

#### Faceting

Another option could be to split your view into two pieces, one with detail on the big values, the other showing all the small values:

```
object_count %>%
  mutate(biggies = if_else(count > 20, "Big", "Little")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(obj_num, count)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~biggies, scales = "free")
```

[image]

#### Lumping

Another option might be too lump together all the counts under 10. The version below emphasizes the object name and count, and the "Other" category has been labeled to show how many values it includes.

```
object_count %>%
  mutate(group = if_else(count < 10, "Others", object)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(avg = mean(count), count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(group = if_else(group == "Others",
                         paste0("Others (n =", count, ")"),
                         group)) %>%
  mutate(group = forcats::fct_reorder(group, avg)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(group, avg)) +
  geom_text(aes(group, avg, label = round(avg, 0)), hjust = -0.5) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

#### Cumulative count (~Pareto chart)

If you're interested in the share of total count, you might also look at the cumulative count and see how the big values make up a large share:

```
object_count %>%
  mutate(cuml = cumsum(count)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(obj_num)) +
  geom_tile(aes(y = count + lag(cuml, default = 0),
            height = count))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! The Lumping way looks like what I want. So for count below 10, it calculates average count (of the 1978 objects in your example)? How do I rename the labels of the 2 axes? Thanks