# Visualize highly skewed count data ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some problems visualizing some highly skewed data (about 70 percent are zeros). I have been looking at the solutions here: [R: suitable plot to display data with skewed counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58567061/r-suitable-plot-to-display-data-with-skewed-counts). I have tried the facetting option, however it doesn't look very good and doesn't seem to capture the distribution of the data properly when count > 10.

Can anyone help with a good way to visualizing the count > 10? Or some other way to visualize the data nicely?

```
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(cutoff = ifelse(count > 10, "count > 10", "count =< 10"))

p1 <- ggplot(data=data, aes(count))
p1 + geom_histogram(bindwidth=1) + facet_grid(.~cutoff, scales="free", labeller = ) 

#Compare the plot above with a table plot like this. 
plot(table(data$count))

#This table plot, shows the distribution much better.. but not in ggplot format.
```

A reproducible examplee:

```
data <- structure(list(count = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 24, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 
0, 8, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 
4, 0, 19, 0, 14, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 20, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
4, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 
0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 
2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 11, 0, 10, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 
2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 1, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 
3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 8, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 7, 0, 23, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 
0, 0, 86, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 
4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 12, 6, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 17, 0, 2, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 13, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 279, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 16, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 26, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 18, 0, 8, 
0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 19, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 5, 0, 4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 13, 0, 23, 0, 1, 
0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 4, 
0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 10, 0, 1, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 11, 
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 16, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 14, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 30, 0, 33, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 
0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
0, 18, 0, 2, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 
8, 0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 22, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 11, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 
16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 14, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 
0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 30, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 10, 0, 8, 0, 22, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 9, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 30, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 8, 
0, 1, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 43, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 9, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 30, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 24, 0, 11, 0, 3, 0, 3, 
0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 20, 
2, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 11, 0, 41, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 85, 
0, 18, 0, 18, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 22, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 25, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 
3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 5, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 51, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
11, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 9, 0, 92, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
14, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 14, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
25, 0, 30, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 22, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 2, 
0, 10, 0, 1, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 40, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 
0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 13, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 12, 0, 3, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 
0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 
0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 22, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 
0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
9, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 11, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0, 20, 0, 4, 0, 9, 0, 4, 0, 22, 0, 22, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 8, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 52, 0, 2, 0, 
5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 37, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 4, 0, 16, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 
0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 27, 
0, 2, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 62, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 2, 10, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
8, 0, 9, 0, 3, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 10, 
0, 11, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 
2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
4, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 11, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 
0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 16, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 12, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 2, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 5, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 5, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 
1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 
0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 
5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 14, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 13, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 34, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 31, 0, 15, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 3, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 
11, 0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 10, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 
0, 10, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 14, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 10, 0, 11, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
4, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -5588L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want full control over ticks and what is displayed, one way to do this is to make the graphs separate and then combine them with `grid.arrange()`. In the example below I made two graphs and changed some features about the x asix (but you can change whatever you like) then put them on the same plot with the gridExtra package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(cutoff = ifelse(count > 10, "count > 10", "count =< 10"))

p1 <- ggplot(data= filter(data, cutoff == "count > 10"), aes(count)) +
      geom_histogram( bins = 10) +
      scale_y_continuous("count", breaks = seq(from = 10, to = 250,by = 10) )

p2 <- ggplot(data=filter(data, cutoff == "count =< 10"), aes(count)) +
  geom_histogram() +
      scale_x_continuous("count", breaks = c(0,2,4,6,8,10))

grid.arrange(p1,p2, ncol =2)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike! This solution solved my problems :-)

Comment: great! And remember if you found a solution helpful hit the up arrow on the side of the question/ click it as accepted!

Comment: I did, Mike!. However, stack overflow doesn't show my voting since my reputation is below 15 :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your approach try this:

```r
p1 <- ggplot(data=data, aes(count))
p1 + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) + 
  facet_wrap(~cutoff, scales ="free_y")
```

Try modifying `binwidth` to get the desired result

Comment: Thank you! Do you how how I can adjust the scale of the graphs separately? I want to break the scale at (0,2,4,6,8,10) in the count < 10 part of the graph and let the other scale start at 10 instead at 11 instead of 0

Comment: It's not easy to manage the ticks in `facet`. You can try `scale = "free"` as a first try. But then you have to have clear in mind what you want: for example, same bin width, same scale, different scales, ...